# creating an instance of a class type variable

Tags: java, oop, constructor, instance-variables

I'm new to OOP and I was wondering how to set something that is not like int, string, double etc.

I have two classes, Foo and Bar, and some instance variables
How can I set the Bar type instance variables?

```
public class Foo
{
    //instance variables
    private String name;        
    Bar test1, test2;

    //default constructor
    public Foo()
    {
        name = "";
        //how would I set test1 and test 2?
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private String nameTest; 

    //constructors
    public Bar()
    {
        nameTest = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Bar test1 = new Bar(); Bar test2 = new Bar(); thats how you create an instance of Bar class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way as anything else, create an instance of a `Bar` and set it on the instance property.

You can create those instances in a constructor, pass them to a constructor, or set with a setter:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar test1;

    public Foo() {
        test1 = new Bar();
    }

    public Foo(Bar bar1) {
        test1 = bar1;
    }

    public void setTest1(Bar bar) {
        test1 = bar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Foo(new Bar());
        f2.setTest1(new Bar());
    }

}
```

Comment: Just found a feature in Eclipse IDE that generates getters and setters for you. But it is good to know otherwise, thanks Dave and everybody else

Comment: @user1615805 Correct, most IDEs will have various code templates, although that's not really related to the question. IIRC Eclipse also has a ctor generation that will take selected properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new instance of `Bar`, using the `new` operator, and assign them to your member variables:

```
public Foo() {
  name = "";
  test1 = new Bar();
  test2 = new Bar();
}
```

#### References:

- [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)
- [Creating Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set  a *Bar* in your default constructor, you'll have to instantiate it.

This is done using the [new operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

`Bar someBar = new Bar();`

You can also create constructors with parameters.

Here's how you would create a *Bar* constructor that takes a String as a parameter:

```
class Bar {

    private String name;

    public Bar(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

}
```

Here's how to use your new *Bar* constructor in *Foo's* default constructor:

```
class Foo {

    private String name;
    private Bar theBar;

    public Foo() {
        name = "Sam";
        theBar = new Bar("Cheers");
    }

}
```

To be even more clever, you could create a new *Foo* constructor that takes two parameters:

```
class Foo {

    private String name;
    private Bar theBar;

    public Foo(String fooName, String barName) {
        name = fooName;
        theBar = new Bar(barName);
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }        
    //getters and setters        
}


public class Student {

    private String school;
    private Person person;

    public Student(Person person, String school) {
        this.person = person;
        this.school = school;
    }        
    //code here
}

class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Person p = new Person("name", 10);
      Student s = new Student(p, "uwu");
   }

}
```

String , Integer, Double etc. also classes like person